# Chrome "Are you sure you want to leave this page" addon

Tags: chrome

On some pages, if you started typing and then accidentally **close** your tab or **navigate** to another page, there would be a confirmation popup:

[image]

However, this is site-dependent and many websites do not support this feature.

Is there a Chrome addon that asks for a confirmation **for every page** when I try to leave a page that has data in `<input>`s and `<textarea>`s?

Comment: (FWIW - you'd *normally* say 'extension' in Chrome rather than 'addon'. Don't know whether that's *technically* correct tho)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ, If I say "extension" people might think I only want "extension". But I welcome "plugins" and "userscripts" too. "[Addon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14380014/632951)" includes all that and all auxiliary stuff.

Comment: Makes sense :) Was just saying what is 'commonly' said :)

Comment: It's a critical security bug in Chrome, and it has been reported by many angry users who wish to disable it, yet the chrome devs won't listen. They are morons, it seems. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=578828#c76

Comment: @EveryoneIsStupid In what way is it a security problem? and why do you link to a page about Firefox when the question is about Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about an *extension* but here's a userscript I've made that does just what you want:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Are you sure you want to leave the page?
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/
// @version      1.0
// @description  Adds a confirmation dialog to all pages you browser that have an input or textarea in it
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/)
// @match        *://*/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var script = document.createElement('script'),
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];   

    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js";            

    if (typeof jQuery=='undefined') {
        head.appendChild(script);
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function () {   
        if($('textarea').length || $('input').length){
            if($.trim($('textarea').val()) != '' || $.trim($('input').val()) != ''){
                return "Do you really want to navigate away? Anything you have written will be lost!";       
            }
        };
    }
}, false);
```

To use it, install [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/), and *then*, [this script](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/raw/master/confirmLeavePage.user.js).

Please do note though that this might trigger on a lot of pages you visit - because almost all websites nowadays have a search bar which is an input! But I've added another check to it to only ask if the fields are *not empty* - so hopefully won't :). You can exclude sites if you want by adding `// @exclude <site_url>` to the metadata block :)